# How to show only blog-domain instead of the whole permalink in the loop

Tags: multisite, permalinks, loop, subdomains

I wanna show the blog URL instead of the whole post URL in my loop.

The reason is that I use Wordpress multiblog with sitewide tags, so on my front-page of the main blog I'm showing the 10 last posts globally. I wanna show the blogdomain the post is coming from.

the_permalink works if I wanna show the whole post-url but I need to cut it down to show only the domain.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/parse-url):

```
echo parse_url( get_permalink(), PHP_URL_HOST );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the function `get_site_url( $blog_id );`

$blog_id is the ID of the blog where your post is from.

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url